# Why the memory used remains big after I free them?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a c code project, it will constantly `malloc/free` memory.

Because I cannot post all code here, so I simplify the code as

1. start it and get a CLI
2. in the CLI, input `start`
3. it will start the process(malloc memory, analyze data, store the data to memory)
4. return to CLI, so the user can type `get stats`, something like this
5. if user type `stop`, it will `free` all previously allocated memory.

I used valgrind to check memory leaks, and there's no memory leak.

What confuses me is that the memory used by the program does not drop after I type `stop`.

Here's some logs

```
$ ./cli
> Welcome, type `help` to get full command list
```

in another terminal

```
$ ps axuwww|grep cli; free -m
sato       6511 0.0 0.0 16016 2072  pts/2 S+   13:48   0:00 ./cli
            total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         3790          88        3615            1         86        3525
```

the program uses 16KB memory

Then go back to previous terminal, and type `start`, after it's done go back to this terminal and run `ps;free`

```
sato       6511 30.3 91.8 4595828 3564516 pts/2 S+   14:13   0:56 ./cli
              total        used        free      shared     buffers       cache   available
Mem:           3790        3581          99           1           0         109          22
```

Then I typed `stop` to free all memory, and use `gdb -p` to attach the process, and verify the array, its freed

and `ps;free` remains the same above output

My question is why its still use about `3581`MB memory, instead of the initial 16KB?

Then I opened another terminal and ran a second `cli` and `start`, after a while, first `cli` process got killed.

I'm using centos7, gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11) (GCC), standard `malloc/free`

Comment: `free` often doesn't return memory to the operating system because it assumes that your program will need it again in the future and it's faster to just keep the memory around inside the program.

Comment: Try to use `mmap`/`munmap` for allocating/freeing large chunks of memory.

Comment: `mmap/munmap` return memory to OS?

Comment: @Marian `mmap(2) is a POSIX-compliant Unix system call that maps files or devices into memory.` I don't want to map files to memory.

Comment: Also I dont `malloc a big size(1GB)`, but `malloc a small size(1MB)` many times(1024, forexample)

Comment: Is this an actual problem you have or are you just worried by some numbers not being what you expected? You can probably just not worry about it. Millions of programs allocate and free a lot of memory, don't return it to the system and most computers run just fine. Systems have been developed over the past 40 years to deal with this.

Comment: Rewrite malloc/realloc/etc/free in the way there are not problems...

Comment: Use `mmap` with flag `MAP_ANONYMOUS`. In this case, `mmap` is only allocating memory. Size of 1MB is O.K.. The point is that `mmap` is allocating memory in sizes which are multiples of memory page size which is usualy 4KB, so it is not usable for a lot of allocations of very small chunks, say 30 bytes, or so.